# monerod in Linux, syntax for path --data-dir

Tags: monerod, linux, blockchain-data

What is the path syntax in Linux?

monerod --data-dir {different drive than monerod}

Drive of \data-mdb is formatted in Windows, monerod runs in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

"{different drive than monerod}" would be the path to the folder containing the data directory.

The default is `/home/yourname/.bitmonero`. If you're trying to use a folder mounted on another drive, it would depend where you mounted that drive. For example, it could be: `/mnt/yourdrive/yourfolder/`, but without knowing where you mounted it, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: The path to the blockchain is X:\block in Windows-syntax and /media/yourname/yourdrive:/block in Linux-syntax. Both tried, both do not work with monerod --data-dir [path].

Comment: But how and where did you mount it?

Comment: I run monero-gui-wallet in Windows and want to change to Linux without moving the blockchain from the current directory, which is my data storage device.